# How to use article and section tags in the best way?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I got confused about section and article tags.I can't choose which one to use
sometimes.for example if I want to make shopping website.is it ok that I use a section tag and then put article tags in it for product card?like this:

```
enter code here

 <section class="products">
     <h2>Phones</h2>
     <article class="product-card"></article>
 </section>
```

Comment: As @takuyakikuchi says, you are using in the right way. MDN is a fantastic resource. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you use `<section>` and `<article>` is perfectly reasonable!

`<section>`

- It is a generic standalone section.
- Should always have a heading, which you do.

[section: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section)

`<article>`
A product card is one of the examples MDN mentions for `<article>`

[article: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article)